# TeXstudio: Run more than one index files

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I am using TeXstudio to write a book, and I would like to include two index files. I am using the document class amsbook with package amsmidx for multiple indices. I succeed to generate two .idx files, and I know that I have to transform them to .ind files in order to compile all stuffs altogether. But I can't, I know only how to run the default .idx file to .ind file but not for these extra .idx files. I will be thankful for any help!

Edit:

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsbook} 

\usepackage{amsmidx}
\makeindex{ind}
\makeindex{sind}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

Symbol\index{sind}{symbol} and object\index{ind}{object}.

\backmatter

\Printindex{ind}{Index}
\Printindex{sind}{Symbol Index}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can execute `makeindex your_file.idx` by hand from terminal and the `ind` will be generated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried with the help of MWE?

Comment: Or maybe you can configure the `makeindex` option in Options menu to execute not only for `%.idx` but `*.idx`.

Comment: @Sigur I have changed %.idx to *.idx in Configure TeXstudio > Commands > Makeindex. Then I run the Makeindex, it shows that: 

Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/makeindex *.idx

Input index file *.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Process exited with error(s)

...and there is no .ind generated.

Comment: @SibaMishra The MWE is added.

Comment: @Sigur Could you explain more about execute makeindex by hand? I am not good at computer programming, what terminal did you mean?

Comment: @Salomo, so `*` was not acceptable. The message says that you can pass the file names separated by spaces like `faa.idx foo.idx` and so on. So, you can at least for a while type the file names there. Do you know the names of the `idx` files you have, right?

Comment: @Sigur A big thanks to you! I got your meaning and proceed all the stuffs well. I will accept it if you put your answer below!

Comment: @Salomo, did you type the file names there? Or did you discovered the wildcard to all files, corresponding to `*`?

Comment: @Sigur I do it manually XD

Comment: @Salomo, let me see if I discover how to type all there. I suppose you are using Mac, so the terminal I said is that black window where you can type commands. It is very useful. I recommend you to try to use it, you can even compile the tex file there running `pdflatex file.tex`.

Comment: @Salomo, I answered below.

Comment: @Sigur Hi, I got a new problem...when doing the makeindex, I got the following reply:

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning input file ind.idx....done (12 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Scanning input file sind.idx....done (9 entries accepted, 2 rejected). Overall 2 files read (21 entries accepted, 2 rejected). Sorting entries....done (97 comparisons). Generating output file ind.ind....done (51 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in ind.ind. Transcript written in ind.ilg.

I wanna know how I can figure out what are rejected?

Comment: @Salomo, it is hard to know without seeing the `\index{}` entries you typed. Probably not related to entries with only letters. So you can try to produce an example like you did with some rejected entry. Also, consider posting another question, since this one is different.

Comment: @Sigur Sorry that I just notice I have done something stupid like typing two items with the same index key XD but thanks!

Comment: @Sigur emmm...I think perhaps it's about another matter...I notice that it shows as error whenever I use the absolute value in the index key, for example, \index{sind}{$|X|$}...could it be fixed??

Comment: @Salomo fresh issue best to raise fresh question, do include just  enough info for others to get same bad result  (MWE)

Comment: From the `ilg` log file we get *Extra '|' at position 4 of first argument*.

Comment: @Salomo, so replace it by `$\vert X\vert$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure TeXstudio to run `makeindex` on a list of files given by names or to run on all `idx` files.

Go to Options > Configure TeXstudio and then Commands tab. You can see the command line corresponding to `makeindex`.

There you pass the `?*.idx` to run on all files.

[image]

After that you can compile your document and run `makeindex` as configures using the Tools > Index menu:

[image]